# Polyline draws a line from wrong location

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, polyline, android-fusedlocation

I developing an app that draws a polyline on users movement. 
For now i got a GoogleMap, and when I launch this app I got a polyline that draws from unknown location to my location. I Just want to start drawing this polyline when user start to move. 
Anyone can tell me whats wrong with my code?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("MYTAG","onCreate()");
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
        Log.d("MYTAG","Google api created!");
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
            .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000) // 1 second, in milliseconds
            .setSmallestDisplacement(10);

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mFusedLocationCallback);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (view != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
            parent.removeView(view);
    }
    try {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.run_fragment, container, false);
    } catch (InflateException e) {
        // Map already created
    }

    if (mMap == null) {
        // Get the map fragment
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myMapid)).getMap();
        // If get map successfully set "Go to my location" button enabled
        if (mMap != null)
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    // Timer widgets
    tv_timer = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.timer);
    b_start_activity = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.b_start_activity);
    b_start_activity.setOnClickListener(this);

    // CountDown widgets
    tv_CountDown = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_countdown);
    iv_CountDownBack = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.iv_countdown);
    // CountDown object
    countDownTimer = new CounterClass(5000,1000);


    return view;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    if (mMap != null) {
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .remove(getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myMapid)).commitAllowingStateLoss();
        mMap = null;
    }
}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (location == null) {
        Log.d("MYTAG","Requesting location updates!");
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, mFusedLocationCallback);
    } else
        updateUI(location);
    Log.d("MYTAG", "GoogleApi is connected! And location time is: " + location.getTime());

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.d("MYTAG", "GoogleApi connection suspended!");
}

 @Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.i("MYTAG", "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }
}

private void updatePolyline(LatLng tempLatlng, LatLng currentLatlng) {
    Log.d("MYTAG","Polyline updated!");
    Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
            .add(tempLatlng, currentLatlng)
            .width(10)
            .color(Color.BLUE));
    line.setVisible(true);
}

 private void updateUI(Location location) {
    Log.d("MYTAG", "Updating your location!");
    LatLng temp = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    // move camera to current location and zoom in
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 16));
    updatePolyline(temp,latLng);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.b_start_activity){
        iv_CountDownBack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tv_CountDown.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        b_start_activity.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        countDownTimer.start();
    }

}

private class LocationCallback implements LocationListener{

    public LocationCallback(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d("MYTAG", "Location changed");
        LatLng temp = new LatLng(latitude, longitude); // Store previouse points
        // Get new points
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        // Call to updateUI to update the UI with correct location on map
        updateUI(location);
    }
}
```